# Bluetooth LE HID Eject Key Code?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I am implementing a dongle based on the TI Bluetooth LE HID sample that needs to restore or disable keyboard functionality. When using an Apple keyboard with an iOS device, pressing the eject button will enable/disable the device, hiding/showing the keyboard.

Most references say there is no key code for the eject button, although one lists it as 161; this does not work when used from a Bluetooth LE device. What are the key codes sent to the device from the keyboard to accomplish this?

I am assuming, of course, that a Bluetooth LE device will send the same key codes as a Bluetooth device, and that Apple's implementation of the Bluetooth LE HID includes the functionality for hiding and restoring the keyboard. If one of these assumptions is incorrect, that would help, too.

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so can you post complete solution? answer below is not clear enough

Comment: Not completely. Unfortunately, the project was canceled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've successfully gotten this working with an Nordic Semiconductor's nRF51822 and S110, using the following report map:

```
static uint8_t report_map_data[] =
{
    0x05, 0x01,                 // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x06,                 // Usage (Keyboard)
    0xA1, 0x01,                 // Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x01,                 //     Report Id (1)
    0x05, 0x07,                 //     Usage Page (Key Codes)
    0x19, 0xe0,                 //     Usage Minimum (224)
    0x29, 0xe7,                 //     Usage Maximum (231)
    0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                 //     Logical Maximum (1)
    0x75, 0x01,                 //     Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x08,                 //     Report Count (8)
    0x81, 0x02,                 //     Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    0x95, 0x01,                 //     Report Count (1)
    0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Size (8)
    0x81, 0x01,                 //     Input (Constant) reserved byte(1)

    0x95, 0x05,                 //     Report Count (5)
    0x75, 0x01,                 //     Report Size (1)
    0x05, 0x08,                 //     Usage Page (Page# for LEDs)
    0x19, 0x01,                 //     Usage Minimum (1)
    0x29, 0x05,                 //     Usage Maximum (5)
    0x91, 0x02,                 //     Output (Data, Variable, Absolute), Led report
    0x95, 0x01,                 //     Report Count (1)
    0x75, 0x03,                 //     Report Size (3)
    0x91, 0x01,                 //     Output (Data, Variable, Absolute), Led report padding

    0x95, 0x06,                 //     Report Count (6)
    0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Size (8)
    0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x65,                 //     Logical Maximum (101)
    0x05, 0x07,                 //     Usage Page (Key codes)
    0x19, 0x00,                 //     Usage Minimum (0)
    0x29, 0x65,                 //     Usage Maximum (101)
    0x81, 0x00,                 //     Input (Data, Array) Key array(6 bytes)

    0x09, 0x05,                 //     Usage (Vendor Defined)
    0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
    0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,           //     Logical Maximum (255)
    0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Count (2)
    0x95, 0x02,                 //     Report Size (8 bit)
    0xB1, 0x02,                 //     Feature (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    0xC0,                        // End Collection (Application)
    // Report ID 2: Advanced buttons
    0x05, 0x0C,                     // Usage Page (Consumer)
    0x09, 0x01,                     // Usage (Consumer Control)
    0xA1, 0x01,                     // Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x02,                     //     Report Id (2)
    0x15, 0x00,                     //     Logical minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                     //     Logical maximum (1)
    0x75, 0x01,                     //     Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x01,                     //     Report Count (1)

    0x0A, 0xAE, 0x01,               //     Usage (AL Keyboard Layout)
    0x81, 0x06,                     //     Input (Data,Value,Relative,Bit Field)
    0xC0                            // End Collection
};
```

Having this report map enables me to send a toggle with this:

```
static void toggle_send(void)
{
    uint32_t err_code;

    uint8_t release = 0;
    uint8_t keyboard_toggle = 0x01;

    // 1 designates the report index, not report ID. 
    err_code = ble_hids_inp_rep_send(&m_hids, 1, sizeof(keyboard_toggle), &keyboard_toggle);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    err_code = ble_hids_inp_rep_send(&m_hids, 1, sizeof(release), &release);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
```

I don't know the TI APIs in detail, but I hope this can be useful to refer to nevertheless. The above modifications should be easy to add to the ble_app_hids_keyboard in the regular nRF51 SDK, if you also have access to that chip.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work in SDK 8 with S110 on nRF51822. The first call to `ble_hids_inp_rep_send` crashes in your example. I noticed you forgot the `&` before `release` in the fourth argument to the second call. Still, I'm unable to make this work. Suggestions? Do you have the full changes to the `hids_keyboard` example available? There are other factors you don't mention, like potentially having to double the size of the `input_report_array`, since there are now two indices, not just one, etc. Many things unclear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mojtaba Did you finally succeed? Could you please show me your full change to the ble_app_hids_keyboard file?

Comment: @user10253771 yes we did, but I don't have the code anymore

Answer (score 0):

this was worked for me:

```
static void hids_init(void)
{
    ret_code_t                    err_code;
    ble_hids_init_t               hids_init_obj;
    ble_hids_inp_rep_init_t     * p_input_report;
    ble_hids_outp_rep_init_t    * p_output_report;
    ble_hids_feature_rep_init_t * p_feature_report;
    uint8_t                       hid_info_flags;

    static ble_hids_inp_rep_init_t     input_report_array[2];
    static ble_hids_outp_rep_init_t    output_report_array[1];
    static ble_hids_feature_rep_init_t feature_report_array[1];
    static uint8_t                     report_map_data[] =
    {
        0x05, 0x01,                 // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
        0x09, 0x06,                 // Usage (Keyboard)
        0xA1, 0x01,                 // Collection (Application)
        0x85, 0x00,                 //     Report Id (1)
        0x05, 0x07,                 //     Usage Page (Key Codes)
        0x19, 0xe0,                 //     Usage Minimum (224)
        0x29, 0xe7,                 //     Usage Maximum (231)
        0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
        0x25, 0x01,                 //     Logical Maximum (1)
        0x75, 0x01,                 //     Report Size (1)
        0x95, 0x08,                 //     Report Count (8)
        0x81, 0x02,                 //     Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

        0x95, 0x01,                 //     Report Count (1)
        0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Size (8)
        0x81, 0x01,                 //     Input (Constant) reserved byte(1)

        0x95, 0x05,                 //     Report Count (5)
        0x75, 0x01,                 //     Report Size (1)
        0x05, 0x08,                 //     Usage Page (Page# for LEDs)
        0x19, 0x01,                 //     Usage Minimum (1)
        0x29, 0x05,                 //     Usage Maximum (5)
        0x91, 0x02,                 //     Output (Data, Variable, Absolute), Led report
        0x95, 0x01,                 //     Report Count (1)
        0x75, 0x03,                 //     Report Size (3)
        0x91, 0x01,                 //     Output (Data, Variable, Absolute), Led report padding

        0x95, 0x06,                 //     Report Count (6)
        0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Size (8)
        0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
        0x25, 0x65,                 //     Logical Maximum (101)
        0x05, 0x07,                 //     Usage Page (Key codes)
        0x19, 0x00,                 //     Usage Minimum (0)
        0x29, 0x65,                 //     Usage Maximum (101)
        0x81, 0x00,                 //     Input (Data, Array) Key array(6 bytes)

        0x09, 0x05,                 //     Usage (Vendor Defined)
        0x15, 0x00,                 //     Logical Minimum (0)
        0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,           //     Logical Maximum (255)
        0x75, 0x08,                 //     Report Count (2)
        0x95, 0x02,                 //     Report Size (8 bit)
        0xB1, 0x02,                 //     Feature (Data, Variable, Absolute)

        0xC0,                        // End Collection (Application)
        // Report ID 2: Advanced buttons
        0x05, 0x0C,                     // Usage Page (Consumer)
        0x09, 0x01,                     // Usage (Consumer Control)
        0xA1, 0x01,                     // Collection (Application)
        0x85, 0x01,                     //     Report Id (2)
        0x15, 0x00,                     //     Logical minimum (0)
        0x25, 0x01,                     //     Logical maximum (1)
        0x75, 0x01,                     //     Report Size (1)
        0x95, 0x01,                     //     Report Count (1)

        0x0A, 0xAE, 0x01,               //     Usage (AL Keyboard Layout)
        0x81, 0x06,                     //     Input (Data,Value,Relative,Bit Field)
        0xC0                            // End Collection
    };

    memset((void *)input_report_array, 0, sizeof(ble_hids_inp_rep_init_t));
    memset((void *)output_report_array, 0, sizeof(ble_hids_outp_rep_init_t));
    memset((void *)feature_report_array, 0, sizeof(ble_hids_feature_rep_init_t));

    // Initialize HID Service
    p_input_report                      = &input_report_array[INPUT_REPORT_KEYS_INDEX];
    p_input_report->max_len             = INPUT_REPORT_KEYS_MAX_LEN;
    p_input_report->rep_ref.report_id   = INPUT_REP_REF_ID;
    p_input_report->rep_ref.report_type = BLE_HIDS_REP_TYPE_INPUT;

    p_input_report->sec.cccd_wr = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_input_report->sec.wr      = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_input_report->sec.rd      = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

// Initialize HID Service
    p_input_report                      = &input_report_array[1];
    p_input_report->max_len             = INPUT_REPORT_KEYS_MAX_LEN;
    p_input_report->rep_ref.report_id   = 1;
    p_input_report->rep_ref.report_type = BLE_HIDS_REP_TYPE_INPUT;

    p_input_report->sec.cccd_wr = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_input_report->sec.wr      = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_input_report->sec.rd      = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_input_report = &input_report_array[INPUT_REPORT_KEYS_INDEX];

    p_output_report                      = &output_report_array[OUTPUT_REPORT_INDEX];
    p_output_report->max_len             = OUTPUT_REPORT_MAX_LEN;
    p_output_report->rep_ref.report_id   = OUTPUT_REP_REF_ID;
    p_output_report->rep_ref.report_type = BLE_HIDS_REP_TYPE_OUTPUT;

    p_output_report->sec.wr = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_output_report->sec.rd = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    p_feature_report                      = &feature_report_array[FEATURE_REPORT_INDEX];
    p_feature_report->max_len             = FEATURE_REPORT_MAX_LEN;
    p_feature_report->rep_ref.report_id   = FEATURE_REP_REF_ID;
    p_feature_report->rep_ref.report_type = BLE_HIDS_REP_TYPE_FEATURE;

    p_feature_report->sec.rd              = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    p_feature_report->sec.wr              = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    hid_info_flags = HID_INFO_FLAG_REMOTE_WAKE_MSK | HID_INFO_FLAG_NORMALLY_CONNECTABLE_MSK;

    memset(&hids_init_obj, 0, sizeof(hids_init_obj));

    hids_init_obj.evt_handler                    = on_hids_evt;
    hids_init_obj.error_handler                  = service_error_handler;
    hids_init_obj.is_kb                          = true;
    hids_init_obj.is_mouse                       = false;
    hids_init_obj.inp_rep_count                  = 2;
    hids_init_obj.p_inp_rep_array                = input_report_array;
    hids_init_obj.outp_rep_count                 = 1;
    hids_init_obj.p_outp_rep_array               = output_report_array;
    hids_init_obj.feature_rep_count              = 1;
    hids_init_obj.p_feature_rep_array            = feature_report_array;
    hids_init_obj.rep_map.data_len               = sizeof(report_map_data);
    hids_init_obj.rep_map.p_data                 = report_map_data;
    hids_init_obj.hid_information.bcd_hid        = BASE_USB_HID_SPEC_VERSION;
    hids_init_obj.hid_information.b_country_code = 0;
    hids_init_obj.hid_information.flags          = hid_info_flags;
    hids_init_obj.included_services_count        = 0;
    hids_init_obj.p_included_services_array      = NULL;

    hids_init_obj.rep_map.rd_sec         = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    hids_init_obj.hid_information.rd_sec = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    hids_init_obj.boot_kb_inp_rep_sec.cccd_wr = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    hids_init_obj.boot_kb_inp_rep_sec.rd      = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    hids_init_obj.boot_kb_outp_rep_sec.rd = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    hids_init_obj.boot_kb_outp_rep_sec.wr = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    hids_init_obj.protocol_mode_rd_sec = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    hids_init_obj.protocol_mode_wr_sec = SEC_JUST_WORKS;
    hids_init_obj.ctrl_point_wr_sec    = SEC_JUST_WORKS;

    err_code = ble_hids_init(&m_hids, &hids_init_obj);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
```